# Sql Server view with very limited access

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, view

I have a requirement to limit a view in **Sql Server 2008 R2** that user:

1. user ***has access*** to select from view.
2. user ***has not access*** to copy the result from select statement.
3. user ***has not access*** to join the view.

I have to use Sql Server view, is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

As soon as someone has access to SELECT from a view, he can also copy the result set and join it with other views or tables, he has access to.

If you need to follow those requirements, you would need to create a custom application, that does not allow copying of data.

Comment: And even then they can write it down or take a screen shot.

Comment: true, that's "physical" security then, that you need to ensure that people cannot take a smartphone or something to take notes...

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole